# Unit tests in phalcon without composer

Tags: phpunit, phalcon

If you look for phalcon phpunits in Google you find the official article from phalcon how to get it to work. In this article is an example TestHelper. Examples are fine - but they need to be described in detail.

First there is created a DI with FactoryDefaults. I don't use FactoryDefaults. Second there are created path constants - why and what do I need (I didn't even find a project tree).

And I thinl the next will throw an error:

include **DIR** . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

I don't want to use composer, npm, grunt, gem or any other packaging helper because I don't like the idea that an external application is doing some "magic" within my project. Download a file and load it I can do by myself and to install an app (like phpunits) I rather use the packaging manager from my os (pacman).

But when I looked into phalcon/incubator there is no such directory vendor and no such file autoload.. How to do it? For what is this file? Where to get it?

Concrete question: how to get unit tests to run without installing composer?

Comment: Composer does no magic. You configure the packages you want in the JSON. Then they're downloaded and an autoloader is generated. You include the autoloader so the classes can be autoloaded when instantiated. Did you ever use it in a real project? If not I'd recommend trying before discarding it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Creating an autoloader, storing files in a predefined structure - that's magic and has nothing to do with my project. So I might have to create an autoloader within tests and add incubator there - to find out what and how I have to install composer, create a new project, create a composer.json and install incubator there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use it without composer you can download or clone the required projects:

> Phalcon Incubator - https://github.com/phalcon/incubator
>   Swiftmailer - https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer
>   Fork-Helper - https://github.com/duncan3dc/fork-helper

Store them to a separate directory and create an autoload.php byself like this one:

```
class UnitTestAutoload
{
    protected $prefixLength = [];
    protected $prefixDirs = [];
    protected $fallbackDirs = [];
    protected $classMap = [];

    public function loadClass($class)
    {
        if ($file = $this->findFile($class)) {
            includeFile($file);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function setNamespaceMapping($prefix, $paths)
    {
        if (!$prefix) {
            $this->fallbackDirs = (array)$paths;
        } else {
            $length = strlen($prefix);
            if ('\\' !== $prefix[$length - 1]) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("A non-empty prefix must end with a namespace separator.");
            }
            $this->prefixLength[$prefix[0]][$prefix] = $length;
            $this->prefixDirs[$prefix] = (array)$paths;
        }
    }

    protected function findFile($class)
    {
        if ('\\' == $class[0]) {
            $class = substr($class, 1);
        }

        if (isset($this->classMap[$class])) {
            return $this->classMap[$class];
        }

        $file = $this->searchFile($class);

        if ($file === null) {
            return $this->classMap[$class] = false;
        }

        return $this->classMap[$class] = $file;
    }

    protected function searchFile($class)
    {
        $logicalPath = strtr($class, '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . '.php';

        $first = $class[0];
        if (isset($this->prefixLength[$first])) {
            foreach ($this->prefixLength[$first] as $prefix => $length) {
                if (0 === strpos($class, $prefix)) {
                    foreach ($this->prefixDirs[$prefix] as $dir) {
                        if (file_exists($file = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . substr($logicalPath, $length))) {
                            return $file;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->fallbackDirs as $dir) {
            if (file_exists($file = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $logicalPath)) {
                return $file;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

function includeFile($file)
{
    include $file;
}

function requireFile($file)
{
    require $file;
}

$_unitTestAutoload = new UnitTestAutoload();
$_unitTestAutoload->setNamespaceMapping('duncan3dc\\Helpers\\', array(__DIR__ . '/duncan3dc/fork-helper/src'));
$_unitTestAutoload->setNamespaceMapping('Phalcon\\', array(__DIR__ . '/phalcon/incubator/Library/Phalcon'));
spl_autoload_register([$_unitTestAutoload, 'loadClass'], true, true);

requireFile(__DIR__ . '/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question right, you are looking for a way to write tests for your Phalcon app that doesn't depend on a solution that can only be installed with Composer.

The bad news is, you definitely need some sort of testing framework, and you will have to integrate it into your project.
The good news, however, that there is a good solution: 
**Codeception**. It's a test framework that has dedicated modules for several PHP frameworks, including Phalcon.

You can install Codeception either via Composer (you don't want that, I get it), or you can simply grab the Phar file.

Basically, what you want to do next is this:

- Run `codecept bootstrap --empty` from your project's root directory
- Create a test suite
- Have it use Codeception's Phalcon2 module and create a bootstrap file for your app
- Perhaps integrate PhantomJS and have Codeception also test your GUI
- Do lots of other cool stuff

This is only a rough guide since your question is a bit too broad to go into details.